# Icon doesn't work/show up

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

Based on [the docs here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html), I added this line:

```
    <icon src="res/icon.png" />
```

Then ran `cordova prepare ios`

Then built and ran the app.

No icon.

What am I not seeing?

(my icon is 1024x1024)

Answer (score 1):

This plugin was the answer:

https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon

I added this to my build process, and I don't need to think about it anymore:

`cordova-icon --icon=icon.png`

Answer (score 0):

After **Cordova 4.4+** for ios, we should specify the sizes of app icon like in document they had given

```
<platform name="ios">
        <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
        <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
        <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
        <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
        <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
        <!-- iPad Pro -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-167.png" width="167" height="167" />
        <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
        <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
        <!-- iPad Pro -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167" />
    </platform>
```